# Select method not found on JArray

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, json.net

I'm using Newtownsoft.Json in my WP8 C# project.

I can't find out why my `JArray` object cannot use the `Select` method in LINQ to JSON.

I have on top of the cs file:

```
using Windows.Data.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Then:

```
  JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
  var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result);
  var lignes = sr.ReadToEnd();
  JObject o = JObject.Parse(lignes);
  JArray featureArray = (JArray)o["features"];
  IList<ItemViewModel> features = featureArray.Select(p => new ItemViewModel ...
```

`.Select` throws a compilation error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` is an extension method in the `System.Linq` namespace.

You need to include

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your code along with your other `using` statements.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Any method not found on JArray. This is it !